# RevTex4-1 figure reference wrong number?

Tags: floats, sectioning, cross-referencing, labels, plot

I have included a graphic using `\includegraphics` into a `\begin{figure} \end{figure}` in revtex4-1. The figure appears in section II (i.e. 2) but the caption of the figure says Fig.1 (this is not a problem per se).

The problem is when I refer to the figure by saying e.g.

`See Figure \ref{Figure: Fig1}` then the output is `See Figure II`. 
I suspect because the figure occurs in section II. How to fix this? Or perhaps this is OK for journals (e.g. J math phys)? Below you can find a MWE

```
    \documentclass{revtex4-1}
    \usepackage{amsmath}
    \usepackage{graphicx}
    \usepackage{verbatim}
    \usepackage{color}
    \usepackage{subfigure}
    \usepackage{hyperref}
    \begin{document}
    \section{First Section}
    hey
    \section{Second Section}
    \begin{figure}
       \includegraphics[width=.5\textwidth]{StupidPicture}\label{Figure: SimplyStupid}
       \caption{This is a stupid picture}
    \end{figure}
Hello dear reader, please see Figure \ref{Figure: SimplyStupid}. Thanks. 
    \end{document}
```

Comment: Since you love learning, you should learn how to provide an [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) ...

Comment: Yeah that part me no love learning

Comment: Well, others will answer it anyway  -- perhaps ;-)

Comment: haha OK, but I'll try with that ME thing from now on, I promise.

Comment: You provided a MWE and we were willing to help ;-)

Comment: `\label` before `\caption` possibly the most F of all FAQ:-) This must be a duplicate....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `\label` must be written after `\caption`, not before. Labels need a `\refstepcounter` (here with `figure` counter) such that the latest stepped counter is known and the reference is correctly written.

If `\label{Figure: SimplyStupid}` is used before `\caption`, it will use the last counter being stepped, this is `section`, that's why the reference prints `II` (the 2nd section)

```
\documentclass{revtex4-1}
    \usepackage{amsmath}
    \usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
    \usepackage{verbatim}
    \usepackage{color}
    \usepackage{subfigure}
    \usepackage{hyperref}
    \begin{document}
    \section{First Section}
    hey
    \section{Second Section}
    \begin{figure}
       \includegraphics[width=.5\textwidth]{StupidPicture}
       \caption{This is a stupid picture}\label{Figure: SimplyStupid}
    \end{figure}
Hello dear reader, please see Figure \ref{Figure: SimplyStupid}. Thanks. 
    \end{document}
```